# how to git move folder and files to new folder and keep history?

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I want to a move folder and files in it to a new folder. Both folder name and file names have changed.

```
Dir1
  file11
  file12

 TO

Dir2
  file21
  file22
```

I also want to keep the history.

Can I do this in one commit? Or I need the following 2 steps?

```
git mv Dir1 Dir2
commit and push

git mv Dir2/file11 Dir2/file21
git mv Dir2/file11 Dir2/file22
commit and push
```

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon part of my question. Want to rename directory and also files in it.

Comment: I am wondering why they made this as duplicate.

This is not duplicate as this question asks how to rename a folder and also files in it. Duplicate question pointed only shows how to rename a folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this in only one commit with:

```
git mv Dir1 Dir2
git mv Dir2/file11 Dir2/file21
git mv Dir2/file11 Dir2/file22
commit and push
```

You can also do this in two commits and squash them using `git rebase -i HEAD~3` if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks it worked.